# Can a static object be fully-cached for HTTPS? (encrypted)

Tags: encryption, https

If I have a static object (file), which being requested by clients via HTTPS - is it possible to cache the file after encryption took place? (for the purpose of saving the processing time of encrypting for each and every client upon request)

Note: I'm not asking how to do it, but rather if it's even possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The encryption keys generated by SSL/TLS will be different for each connection. One component of the key-derivation is a client-generated nonce, so the server has no way of pre-calculating the key.

Comment: So it's not even per client, but per connection? so if the same client opens 2 connections for 2 separated requests, the keys will be different - hence one need to re-encrypt it?

Comment: Yes. Even worse, if the same object is sent twice on the same connection, the encryption-state will have changed, so the encryption will be different.

Answer (score 0):

By sending Cache-Control: public many browsers will cache content even if it is sent over SSL.

IE, and FF3+ should respect this.

EDIT: Sorry misread the question.
You can also store content after encryption using some sort of proxy server.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response, but according to Rasmus Faber, it's impossible to cache the encrypted form of a static object, due to a different key upon connection.

Comment: It's indeed not possible to cache content sent over SSL/TLS on an HTTP proxy server (mainly because it's still encrypted when it goes through the proxy), however, it's possible to cache content on a client for further subsequent requests by the same client. SSL/TLS is about transport security; once the content has reached its destination, it is no longer encrypted and may potentially be cached by the client itself, as Matt said.

Comment: Quite right. I was getting a little confused, as I had configured something similar. What I was thinking of was having an app server that transferred unencrypted content, and having nginx or some other proxy perform the encryption on the cached content.